# dplyr::select_if can use colnames and their values at the same time?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to select cols using colnames and their values in a single pipe chain without referring other objects, such as `NAMES <- names(d)`. Can I do it with `select_if()` ?

For example,

I can use colnames to select cols.
(`select(matches(...))` is smarter treating only colnames).

```
library(dplyr)
d <- iris %>% select(-Species) %>% tibble::as.tibble()

d %>% select_if(stringr::str_detect(names(.), "Petal"))
```

And I can use the values.

```
d %>% select_if(~ mean(.) > 5)
```

But how to use both of them ? (especially OR)
Below code is what I want (of course, don't run).

```
d %>% select_if(stringr::str_detect(names(.), "Petal") | ~ mean(.) > 5)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A workaround that is not too complicated is:

```
d %>% select_if(stringr::str_detect(names(.), "Petal") | sapply(., mean) > 5)

# or 
d %>% select_if(grepl("Petal",names(.)) | sapply(., mean) > 5)
```

Which gives:

```
# A tibble: 150 x 3
   Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width
          <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
 1          5.1          1.4         0.2
 2          4.9          1.4         0.2
 3          4.7          1.3         0.2
 4          4.6          1.5         0.2
 5          5.0          1.4         0.2
 6          5.4          1.7         0.4
 7          4.6          1.4         0.3
 8          5.0          1.5         0.2
 9          4.4          1.4         0.2
10          4.9          1.5         0.1
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I was strugging to lambda functions but it isn't necessary.

Comment: @cuttlefish44, sure. The problem of functions is that function in `.predicate` is applied to columns and by this way we loose the information of names.

Comment: Another option is `d %>% select(matches("Petal"), names(which(map(., mean) > 5)))`

Comment: @akrun; Thanks for your comment. I noticed that `names()` don't necessary. Thanks to you and @mt1022, I was able to deepen my understanding.