# select non-missing variables in a purrr loop

Tags: r, dplyr, lm, purrr

Consider this example

```
mydata <- data_frame(ind_1 = c(NA,NA,3,4),
                     ind_2 = c(2,3,4,5),
                     ind_3 = c(5,6,NA,NA),
                     y = c(28,34,25,12),
                     group = c('a','a','b','b'))

> mydata
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  ind_1 ind_2 ind_3     y group
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1    NA     2     5    28 a    
2    NA     3     6    34 a    
3     3     4    NA    25 b    
4     4     5    NA    12 b
```

Here I want, for each `group`, regress `y` on whatever variable is not missing in that group, and store the corresponding `lm` object in a `list-column`.

That is:

- for group `a`, these variables correspond to `ind_2` and `ind_3`
- for group `b`, they correspond to `ind_1` and `ind_2`

I tried the following but this does not work

```
mydata %>% group_by(group) %>% nest() %>% 
  do(filtered_df <- . %>% select(which(colMeans(is.na(.)) == 0)),
     myreg = lm(y~ names(filtered_df)))
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `map` and `mutate`. We can either `select` and model in one step (`nestdat1`) or in separate steps using two `map`'s if you want to preserve the filtered data (`nestdat2`):

```
library(tidyverse)

nestdat1 <- mydata %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = data %>% map(~ select_if(., funs(!any(is.na(.)))) %>%
                                lm(y ~ ., data = .)))

nestdat2 <- mydata %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = data %>% map(~ select_if(., funs(!any(is.na(.))))),
         model = data %>% map(~ lm(y ~ ., data = .)))
```

**Output:**

They produce different `data` columns:

```
> nestdat1 %>% pull(data)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  ind_1 ind_2 ind_3     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA     2     5    28
2    NA     3     6    34

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  ind_1 ind_2 ind_3     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     4    NA    25
2     4     5    NA    12

> nestdat2 %>% pull(data)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  ind_2 ind_3     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     5    28
2     3     6    34

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  ind_1 ind_2     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     4    25
2     4     5    12
```

But the same `model` column:

```
> nestdat1 %>% pull(model)
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        ind_2        ind_3  
         16            6           NA  

[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        ind_1        ind_2  
         64          -13           NA  


> nestdat2 %>% pull(model)
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        ind_2        ind_3  
         16            6           NA  

[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        ind_1        ind_2  
         64          -13           NA
```

Comment: just a follow up. how can I manually add a few extra variables to the `select_if`?

Comment: say, keep the variables that are non-missing, but also keep the variable `date`

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ That's more complicated, but feasible I guess with something like: `mydata %>% select_if(sapply(., function(x) !any(is.na(x))) | grepl("date", names(.)))` or `mydata %>% select(matches("date"), names(.)[map_lgl(., ~!any(is.na(.)))])`

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032969/dplyrselect-if-can-use-colnames-and-their-values-at-the-same-time

Comment: haha I saw, I am trying to replace the `sapply(., mean) ` by `map` here...

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ With `map` it would be `mydata %>% select_if(map_lgl(., ~ !any(is.na(.))) | grepl("date", names(.)))
`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `tidyverse` option, assign to `mydata$model` if you wish to keep it in your `tibble` :

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
  nest(-group) %>%
  pull(data) %>%
  map(~lm(y ~., discard(.,anyNA)))
# [[1]]
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ ., data = discard(., anyNA))
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)        ind_2        ind_3  
#          16            6           NA  
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ ., data = discard(., anyNA))
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)        ind_1        ind_2  
#          64          -13           NA  
# 
#
```